Using WithQuery API In NativeQueryBuilder Of Elastic Search
With the previous version of spring data elastic search and RestHighLevelClient i was able to use the BoolQueryBuilder with NativeSearchQuery and NativeSearchQueryBuilder as shown below
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.must(new TermsQueryBuilder("field", flVal));
NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();   
searchQueryBuilder.withQuery(boolQueryBuilder); 
NativeSearchQuery queryn = searchQueryBuilder.build();
elasticsearchTemplate = new ElasticsearchTemplate(elasticsearchClient);
hits = elasticsearchTemplate.search(queryn, "indexName");

Now i want to upgrade the elastic search along with spring data elastic search and use the EaslticSearchClient instead of ResHighLevelClient where the NativeSearchQueryBuilder and NativeSearchQuery are deprecated and asked to replace with NativeQuery and NativeQueryBuilder but iam not able to retain the withQuery API as it shows compilation exception as shown below
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.must(new TermsQueryBuilder(fieldName+".keyword", flVal));
NativeQueryBuilder searchQueryBuilder = new NativeQueryBuilder();   
searchQueryBuilder.withQuery(boolQueryBuilder); /* This throws compilation exception */

How can i retain the withQuery API.

Please provide your previous version and current verison.

Previous Version : spring-data-elasticsearch 5.1.0, elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client 7.17.23,elasticsearch-x-content 7.17.23,elasticsearch-core 7.17.9,elasticsearch-7.17.23
Current Version: spring-data-elasticsearch 5.3.4,elasticsearch-rest-client 8.15.2,elasticsearch-x-content 8.15.2,elasticsearch-core 8.15.2,elasticsearch 8.15.2,elasticsearch-java 8.15.2                                              Removed elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client dependency in current version as i want to use ElasticsearchClient
